# passing consecutive single quotes in xpath function

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping

I am sending some sql query from xslt to extension function like below:

```
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="ext:ExecuteSQL(concat('select * from [TABLE1] where COLUMN1=&apos;',name,'&apos;'))"/>
```

The error I am getting is `expected token ')', found 'name'`, I guess it is due to the successive occurrance of `&apos;` and `'`. So, how can I escape this character?

Comment: Your second `&apos` is missng a semi-colon at the end. Is this a typo in your question?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: anyways, i solved the problem by interchanging single and double quotes for the select attribute.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question. That is to say, write it out as an answer, rather than a comment, as it may be beneficial to other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by interchanging single and double quotes for the select attribute, as shown below:

```
<xsl:variable name="var1" select='ext:ExecuteSQL(concat("select * from [TABLE1] where COLUMN1=&apos;",name,"&apos;"))'/>
```